# make focused button look like non-focussed button

Tags: css, sass

Within a specific div, I want to make focused buttons to look exactly like non-focused buttons.

Is there a way I can express that in sass/scss?

Something similar to this:

```
.myDiv {

 > button {

    &:focus {
      @extend &:not(&:focus)
    }
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, can I disable all rules that are applied only because of the definition for pseudo-class `:focus` ?

Comment: AFAIK scss @extend only works on classes and placeholder classes

Comment: Why not simply `> button, > button:focus {`?

Comment: @Connum because button:focus might inherit rules from somewhere else that I want to be overriden

Answer (score 2):

You could use [placeholder selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors). Something along the lines of this:

```sass
%button {
    color: red;
}

button {
    @extend %button;

    &:focus {
        color: green;
    }
}

.myDiv {
    > button:focus {
        // Extend from %button again, thus overriding through specificity.
        @extend %button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply overwrite the default styling by doing this below

```css
.myDiv {
 > button {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```

If you needed to use extend, you could do something like this

```css
%no-focus {
   outline: none;
}

.myDiv {
 > button {
    &:focus {
      @extend %no-focus;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I advise you read [this article](https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/) from the a11y project - which explains why in terms of it's not good to un-style `:focus`'d elements in terms of accessibility.

Comment: It is actually not about outline, it is about some style defined somewhere else in the project which I want to not be applied in this case.

Comment: Ah, would it not be easier to just make a class (or placeholder) that overwrites the styles you want to remove and then `@extend` that? For example, if you dont want `background: red;` to be on this button, create a placeholder with `background: none;` (you may need `!important`) and then just extend that class on the elements you don't want to have the red background? @Ferenjito

Answer (score 0):

Here, I explain simply. Please see the code below.

HTML:

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
.mydiv {
  button {
    border: 1px solid #000;

    &:focus {
      border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
  }
}
```